# Not able to run mongodb version 4.0 on my local machine

Tags: mongodb

Getting this error when I try to run command `mongo`:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-07-24T13:08:13.968+0800 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

After run this command `sudo service mongod status` Its giving me output something like this :

```
mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Sel 2018-07-24 13:18:18 +08; 45s ago
Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
Process: 18153 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)
Main PID: 18153 (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)
root@him: systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
root@him: mongod[18153]: 2018-07-24T13:18:18.777+0800 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to f
root@him: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT
root@him: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
root@him: mongod.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
```

Comment: start your mongod service... `sudo service mongod start` or check your status `sudo service mongod status`

Comment: Yeah! I am trying this but still getting the same error :(

Comment: Type `systemctl list-unit-files --type=service` and check for mongod.service  in the list if it is disabled then run `sudo systemctl enable mongodb.service` and check it again by `systemctl list-unit-files --type=service`

Comment: It's already enabled  ```mongod.service      enabled ```

Comment: Ok try these steps https://askubuntu.com/questions/748789/run-mongodb-service-as-daemon-of-systemd-on-ubuntu-15-10

Comment: I just see my ```mongodb.service``` is ```masked``` and getting an error when trying to enable it ```Failed to execute operation: Unit file is masked
```

Comment: It's working now I just reinstall the MongoDB and now my configuration in ```mongod.service``` is ```enabled``` and ```mongodb.service``` is ```masked```

Answer (score 1):

The data files are created under root not the mongodb user when you run from the terminal.

You need to give permissions:

```
cd /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb *
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, maybe because of ubuntu upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04. Could not start `mongod` manually, the reason was absence of `/data/db` and its permissions. Then `mongod` would start manually but still errorring on `mongodb.service`. At the end reinstalling mongodb worked. It was a new install so did not care about backups.

```
$ sudo apt remove mongodb mongo-tools mongodb-clients mongodb-server mongodb-server-core
$ sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mongodb/
$ sudo apt install mongodb
```